# How to get given and family from a pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column name fullname:

```
    fullname
Andres Kirk Polsky
Anna Lorensen Polsman Uirch
```

I want to create two new columns like:

```
fullname                        given       rest_name
Andres Kirk Polsky              Andres      Kirk Polsky
Anna Lorensen Polsman Uirch     Anna        Lorensen Polsman Uirch
```

I am trying use `str.aplit(' ', expand=True`) but this no giving the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *regex* approach would be to use [`pandas.Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) :

```
df[["given", "rest_name"]] = (df["fullname"].str.extractall(r"^(\S+)\s(.*)")
                                              .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                      fullname   given               rest_name
0           Andres Kirk Polsky  Andres             Kirk Polsky
1  Anna Lorensen Polsman Uirch    Anna  Lorensen Polsman Uirch
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
(df.assign(**df['fullname'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
           .rename({0: 'given', 1: 'rest_name'}, axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
                      fullname   given               rest_name
0           Andres Kirk Polsky  Andres             Kirk Polsky
1  Anna Lorensen Polsman Uirch    Anna  Lorensen Polsman Uirch
```